# Bash. Hex to ascii. Is possible without xxd or perl?

Tags: hex, ascii

I'm developing a script on which I have a hex string `31323334353637383930313233` and I want to transform it into ASCII. Desired output is `1234567890123`.

I already have it working using:

```
echo "31323334353637383930313233" | xxd -r -p
```

or

```
echo "31323334353637383930313233" | perl -pe 's/(..)/chr(hex($1))/ge'
```

But the point is try to use the minimum possible requirements for the script. I want it working in suse, fedora, debian, ubuntu, arch, etc... It seems the xxd command is included in vim package. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this using only awk or any internal Linux tool which is going to be present by default in all Linux systems.

Comment: I would have said you would be hard pressed to find many systems that do not have perl on them.

Comment: @grail most of the UNIX systems I've had to work with haven't had perl on them and I wasn't authorized to install it so YMMV.

Comment: @EdMorton the OP did mention linux and I have never worked on one that doesn't have perl :)

Comment: idk I've never worked on anything that ran linux AFAIK. Or maybe I have and just don't remember it. In any case, he listed a whole bunch of different platforms and I would be surprised if they're all Linux so I assumed that, as many people do these days, he was misusing the term Linux and actually meany UNIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate (g)awk solution:

```
echo "31323334353637383930313233" | awk 'RT{printf "%c", strtonum("0x"RT)}' RS='[0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: I chose this because is the simplest and awk is already a requirement for my script. Nice! thanks.

Comment: hey @grail, this works for hex strings which don't contain any letter... but what about hex strings containing some chars? can be this improved? This for example `4A656E6E793230303031303130` Thanks

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis simply add A-F to character class -- [0-9A-F]

Answer (score 4):

Found this script [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/%5Bbash%5D-ascii-to-hex-and-hex-to-ascii-488357/):

```
#!/bin/bash
function hex2string () {
  I=0
  while [ $I -lt ${#1} ];
  do
    echo -en "\x"${1:$I:2}
    let "I += 2"
  done
}
hex2string "31323334353637383930313233"
echo
```

You may change the line `hex2string "31323334353637383930313233"` so that it takes the hex value from parameters, that is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hex2string () {
  I=0
  while [ $I -lt ${#1} ];
  do
    echo -en "\x"${1:$I:2}
    let "I += 2"
  done
}
hex2string "$1"
echo
```

So when executed as:

```
./hexstring.sh 31323334353637383930313233
```

It will provide the desired ascii output.

NOTE: Can't test if it works in all Linux systems.

Answer (score 4):

Using [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk), from `HEX` to `ASCII`

```
$ gawk  '{ 
           gsub(/../,"0x& "); 
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              printf("%c", strtonum($i)); 
           print "" 
}' <<<"31323334353637383930313233"
1234567890123
```

Using any [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$ cat hex2asc_anyawk.awk 
BEGIN{
    split("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F", d, / /)
    for(i in d)Decimal[d[i]]=i-1
}

function hex2dec(hex,  h,i,j,dec)
{ 
    hex = toupper(hex);                
    i   = length(hex);                 
    while(i)
    {  
          dec += Decimal[substr(hex,i,1)] * 16 ^ j++
          i--                          
    }
    return dec;
}
{

    gsub(/../,"& "); 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf("%d",hex2dec($i));
    print ""
}
```

**Execution**

```
$ awk -f hex2asc_anyawk.awk <<<"31323334353637383930313233"
1234567890123
```

> **Explanation**

Steps :

1. Get the decimal equivalent of hex from table.
2. Multiply every digit with 16 power of digit location.
3. Sum all the multipliers.

[image]

[image]

**Example :**

[image]

```
BEGIN{
    # Here we created decimal conversion array, like above table
    split("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F", d, / /)
    for(i in d)Decimal[d[i]]=i-1
}

function hex2dec(hex,  h,i,j,dec)
{ 
    hex = toupper(hex);                 # uppercase conversion if any A,B,C,D,E,F
    i   = length(hex);                  # length of hex string
    while(i)
    {  
          # dec var where sum is stored
          # substr(hex,i,1) gives 1 char from RHS
          # multiply by 16 power of digit location 
          dec += Decimal[substr(hex,i,1)] * 16 ^ j++
          i--                           # decrement by 1
    }
    return dec;
}
{
    # it modifies record
    # suppose if given string is 31323334353637383930313233
    # after gsub it becomes 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33
    # thus re-evaluate the fields

    gsub(/../,"& "); 

    # loop through fields , NF gives no of fields
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

        # convert from hex to decimal
        # and print equivalent ASCII value 
        printf("%c",hex2dec($i));

    # print newline char
    print ""
}
```

> Meaning of  `dec += Decimal[substr(hex,i,1)] * 16 ^ j++`

```
dec += Decimal[substr(hex,i,1)] * 16 ^ j++
 ^           ^                    ^
 |           |                    | 
 |           |                    2.Multiply every digit with 16 power of digit location.
 |           |    
 |           1.Gives decimal equivalent of hex
 | 
 | 
 3. Sum all the multipliers
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a special cheating trick for u - due to ingenuity of how they originally mapped decimal digits to bytes, their hex are all `x3[0-9]`,

so therefore, if u already know they would decode out to digits and nothing else, here's a fast shortcut :

```
 echo "31323334353637383930313233" |
```

> ```
> mawk 'gsub("..","_&") + gsub("_3",_)^_'
> ```

```
1234567890123
```

if it's already URL-percent-encoded, then it's even simpler :

```
 echo '%31%32%33%34%35%36%37%38%39%30%31%32%33' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'gsub("%3",_)^_'
>                         or
> gawk ++NF FS='%3' OFS=
> ```

```
1234567890123
```

This specialized approach can handle hex of absolutely any arbitrary size, even for `awk`s that don't have built-in support for `bigint`s

```
TL;DR : don't "do math" when none is needed
```

Answer (score 0):

for a `gawk` specific solution that's only barely longer than the `perl` solution, just use the `-n` flag and skip the extra call to `strtonum()` ::

— (`-P` could also read hex, but much slower than `-n + -b`)

```
echo '31323334353637383930313233' |
```

---

```
gawk -nb '/./ || $_ = sprintf("%c", +("0x" RT))' RS=.. ORS=
```

---

```
1234567890123
```